# When trying to expand the fields of a sharepoint list item returns http response 401

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, beta

I am using the beta microsoft graph request to expand the fields of a list item. Like this:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items/{item-id}?expand=fields
```

According to my permissions I comply the prereqs with Sites.ReadWrite.All. But still I receive 401 with the following response body:

```
{
"error": {
    "code": "unauthenticated",
    "message": "Access denied. You are not authorized to perform this operation or open this resource.",
    "innerError": {
        "request-id": "xxx-xx-xxx-xx-xxxxxxxxx",
        "date": "2017-05-30T08:46:28"
    }
}
```

}

**Edit:**
Even without the expand the response is now 401. So requesting a single item also gives a 401. The used http request and headers are:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/xxxxxxxxxxx.sharepoint.com,2f72ee36-b572-4919-bc5f-66a41f8fd128,f01a93c4-ce7a-4b37-b214-d868d39204ef/lists/fa190d14-7ab0-42a3-860d-d1cde4d93ccf/items/853adfa7-d114-425c-998f-54a58496bfbc HTTP/1.1
Host: graph.microsoft.com
Connection: keep-alive
Origin: https://developer.microsoft.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36
Authorization: Bearer yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
Referer: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch, br
Accept-Language: nl-NL,nl;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
```

The response:

```
    HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
    Cache-Control: private
    Content-Type: application/json
    request-id: xxx-xx-xxx-xx-xxxxxxxxx
    client-request-id: xxx-xx-xxx-xx-xxxxxxxxx
    x-ms-ags-diagnostic: {"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"West Europe","Slice":"SliceA","ScaleUnit":"002","Host":"AGSFE_IN_1","ADSiteName":"AMS"}}
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
    Access-Control-Expose-Headers: ETag, Location, Preference-Applied, Content-Range, request-id, client-request-id
    Duration: 320.1951
    Date: Wed, 31 May 2017 08:43:44 GMT
    Content-Length: 298

{
  "error": {
    "code": "unauthenticated",
    "message": "Toegang geweigerd. U bent niet gemachtigd om deze bewerking uit te voeren of deze bron te openen.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "xxx-xx-xxx-xx-xxxxxxxxx",
      "date": "2017-05-31T08:43:44"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the HTTP request you're sending (headers, options, body, etc.)?

Comment: @MarcLaFleur-MSFT I've edited my post with extra information

Comment: Thank you. Are you able to access this list via SharePoint? This message implies the user you have authenticated does not have access to this list.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur-MSFT, yes I have acces with this account. I am also able to PUT a file to the same documentlibrary using: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,2f72ee36-b572-4919-bc5f-66a41f8fd128,f01a93c4-ce7a-4b37-b214-d868d39204ef/drives/b!Nu5yL3K1GUm8X2akH4_RKMSTGvB6zjdLshTYaNOSBO8UDRn6sHqjQoYN0c3k2TzP/root/children/test.txt/content. My final goal is to upload a file using this command and set metadata by updating fields on that file (metadata). If you need any other info please let me know.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur-MSFT any news? For me this is still a problem. I know it is beta but still I wouild like to get this to work. I've marked all permissions (not the ones with admin privileges needed) and still I am unable to retrieve the listitem

Comment: @MarcLaFleur-MSFT, I've changed to another account. Difference with my previous account that this one is granted access to the sharepoint root site (xxxxxxxxxxx.sharepoint.com). While the other account only has access to several sitecollections. xxxxxxxxxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/sitecol1, xxxxxxxxxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/sitecol2 and so on. Guess what, with my new account I can now get item information and I am able to get and patch fields. Is this a know feature?